# Opening third party applications in hidden, minimise, maximize etc states from Matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I am looking for simple solution to open a third part application (.exe) from within Matlab with predefined window status (of the application being opened).

Something as elegant as VB Shell command:
Shell("path to exe"), vbHide or vbMaximizedFocus etc

I have tried loading user32.dll so that I could use that calllib function to change window state but "The function call type stdcall is not supported" error keeps hitting me. I have tried to resolve it by giving it a proper header file but now given up. Also I am not sure if this method will keep working after compiling the application (using Matlab application compiler).

There must be another simple way! May be using a simple Java class and using that in Matlab?

Comment: What applications are you trying to open ?

Comment: I am trying to open a third party application pertaining to oil and gas sector. It is just like any other application which gets fired through an exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `system` function to execute operating system commands from Matlab.

To start an application from command line in a minimized state you can use `start /min` command, e.g. to start notepad from command line you could run:

```
start /min "" "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
```

Therefore you can do the same from Matlab with the following command:

```
system('start /min "" "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"');
```

For the full parameter list of `start` windows command refer to [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx).

Comment: And I feel stupid now. And never got say thank you for introducing me to try Java methods of Matlab. It has been enlightening experience ever since!